# Is it possible to dynamically load an html template with angular components to a angular app which is AOT compiled?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-aot

In my angular application, back-end users can create custom templates. Those custom templates need to be loaded in the angular application at specific positions. I have a custom directive which gets templates 
( based on the routes) from the CMS and inject it to my angular application. If I put it into the `innerHTML` the components will not get rendered correctly. I need `componentFactoryResolver` and `compiler` to properly show the components.

The above solution does not work with `AOT` compilation. Is there any other way I can achieve the same and make use of `AOT`? Is server side rendering is only solution to this?

Comment: If you still need something for this, this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48827024/8107466

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't encourage using Compiler to create dynamic template.

[Could/would/will code using COMPILER_PROVIDERS be supported by AOT?](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11780)

But maybe in future it will be possible with without shipping the compiler because new **View Engine** open new capabilities.

**Properties**

the generated code relies on very few internals.

- we can make the API public and stable
- users could ship the generated factory files on npm

  this makes calls to `ngc` in applications faster as it does not need
  to compile the code of libraries like Ionic any more.
- users could implement their own `ViewEngine`

  this way we can drop the `Renderer` abstraction, as we already have an indirection via the `ViewEngine`
- **users could create templates programmatically during runtime**

  **without shipping the compiler**

  eg for a dynamic form / ....

  we might want to provide a `builder` for this that calculates indices correctly and can already be used in tests
- we could create a new kind of directive **that transforms a `ViewDefinition`**, e.g. wraps elements into new ones, ... (**similar to the `compile` in Angular 1**).

  needs some helpers that maps indices from new to original indices

Read more in [Design Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/195L4WaDSoI_kkW094LlShH6gT3B7K1GZpSBnnLkQR-g/preview) for View Engine

Comment: Thankyou. You said 'Angular doesn't encourage using Compiler to create dynamic template.' ? So what is the suggested solution in this case?